# Svg font workaround for Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I have the following SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 18 22">
<defs >
<font horiz-adv-x="830" ><font-face
font-family="one"
units-per-em="1000"
panose-1="2 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0"
ascent="707"
descent="-48"
alphabetic="0" />
<glyph unicode="e" glyph-name="e" horiz-adv-x="1038" d="M164 206T153 206T135 213T127  
233V301Q127 332 145 350T197 368H618Q642 368 650 393Q662 435 696 461T781 487Q838 487 879 
448T921 349Q921 289 880 250T781 210Q748 210 721 225T684 253T672 270Q660
291 682 304Q702 315 714 295Q735 260 781 260Q817 260 843 286T869 349Q869 385 843 411T781  
437Q757 437 740 430T714 409T701 388T694 368Q678 318 628 318H306V233Q306 220 299 213T280 
206T262 213T254 233V318H207Q179 318 179 290V233Q179 220 172 213Z"
/>
</font>
</defs>


<text font-family="one" x="100" y="100">e</text>

</svg>
```

Obviously as Firefox has postponed SVG font support indefinitely I should serve something differently to firefox, so I am looking for an svg hack that will allow me to give FF a path, and other browsers a font.

Comment: Why not just convert the font to something Firefox does support like woff. There are plenty of online converters that will do that.

Comment: unfortunately I doubt it is going to be accepted that we use both Woff and SVG, we are using svg for some icons. Two of the icons were actually part of a font purchased at one point, so I converted the glyphs, and would like to serve a fallback path in the case that the font is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The font-family attribute in SVG allows a list of fallback fonts, as in CSS, so you could use:

```
<text font-family="one, 'Courier New', monospace" x="100" y="100">e</text>
```

In SVG-font compatible browsers you would get your font, in others it would fall back to the next one on the list.